# Counting instances in a file, less or equal to

Tags: python

I cannot seem to be able to get this working. I have a txt file where in one line, there are number up to 250000 and in the other, there are numbers from 0 to 4. I want to count how many times there are instances where the number is less of equal to 50000 and has corresponding number 0. I would like to then write it to a file. For some reason, it doesnt recognize any instances where the number is less of equal to 50000.

```
import sys 
import argparse 
import operator

def main (argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get the variants that are present at least 5% of the time ')
    parser.add_argument('infile', help='file to process')
    parser.add_argument('outfile', help='file to produce')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    results =[]
    c0 = int("0")
    count = 0
    a = int("50000")

    with open(args.infile, "r") as f, open(args.outfile, "w") as of:
        file_in = f.readlines()
        for line in file_in:
            temp = line.split()
            if temp[0]<= a and temp[1]== c0:
                count+=1
                first_trajectory_cluster0 = str(count)
                of.write(first_trajectory_cluster0 + "cluster0" + "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Use `if int(temp[0]) <= a ...`, as `temp[0]` is a string. Also, `a = int("50000")` is simply `a = 50000`.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a string to an integer in each case:

```
        temp = line.split()
        if temp[0]<= a and temp[1]== c0:
```

You need to convert:

```
        temp = line.split()
        if int(temp[0]) <= a and int(temp[1]) == c0:
```